# How to expire a cache on Aliyun (Alibaba Cloud) CDN using all files last update date?

Tags: cdn, alibaba-cloud

I'm running a static blazor WASM app and when I update the files, Aliyun continues to serve the old files causing the app to crash.

I tried to do this manually using the `CDN/Refresh and Prefetch` method in the console which works, but since my CDN is a wildcard domain `https://*.xxx.com` I can't manually each subdomain when the blazor app is updated. And when I try to use a regex, it won't accept `https://[a-z]+[.]mydomain[.]com/` because "Only the four specified regular expressions are supported. Characters such as * + {} [ ] \ ^ | must not be included." - and when I tried to use one of the allowed regex expressions such as `https://[^/]*.mydomain.com/` it reports and error also.

Someone mentioned that I could set up a trigger (PutObject) using a function, but I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Is your app stored in Alibaba OSS? If so, you can setup a function [trigger](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/en/fc/overview-of-oss-event-triggers) . Whenever you update the files, the change trigger a function execution. The function can call CDN API to [refresh caches](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/en/cdn/developer-reference/api-cdn-2018-05-10-refreshobjectcaches?spm=a2c63.p38356.0.0.3dff7fb3BpzAzN).

Comment: I looked at that - but I don't think calling `RefreshObjectCaches` will work if the same file is accessed via different subdomains? (e.g. https://sub1.mydomain.com/index.html, https://sub2.mydomain.com/index.html, https://subn.mydomain.com/index.html, )

Looking at the docs: the `ObjectPath` request parameter has this as an example: http://example.com/image/1.png

Comment: Yes, OSS. There is a setting in OSS to ["Auto CDN cache update"](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/en/cdn/files-downloaded-by-using-alibaba-cloud-cdn-are-inconsistent) but it does not support wildcard domains